# How to pass a trained model to KerasClassifier?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I have a dozen pre-trained Keras DNNs that I wish to add to an sklearn ensemble. The issue is that it seems I can not provide pre-trained models to *KerasClassifier*. *KerasClassifier* might only exist to create new, untrained models.

```
classifier_models = []
# The models variable contains a dict of pre-trained models.
for name, model in models: 
    try:
        # This line raises an error if we use a pre-trained DNN.
        model._estimator_type

        classifier_models.append((name, model))
    except:
        # If we got a pre-trained Keras DNN, we must wrap it, then...
        new_model = KerasClassifier(model=model)
  
        # ...we set the _estimator_type and...
        new_model._estimator_type = 'classifier'

        # ...we continue the standard procedure.
        classifier_models.append((name, new_model))
```

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11744/990400553.py in <module>
      3     try:
----> 4         model._estimator_type
      5         classifier_models.append((name, model))

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_estimator_type'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11744/990400553.py in <module>
      5         classifier_models.append((name, model))
      6     except:
----> 7         new_model = KerasClassifier(model=model)
      8         new_model._estimator_type = 'classifier'
      9         classifier_models.append((name, new_model))

~\miniconda3\envs\epfl-ml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn.py in __init__(self, build_fn, **sk_params)
     75     self.build_fn = build_fn
     76     self.sk_params = sk_params
---> 77     self.check_params(sk_params)
     78 
     79   def check_params(self, params):

~\miniconda3\envs\epfl-ml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn.py in check_params(self, params)
     91     ]
     92     if self.build_fn is None:
---> 93       legal_params_fns.append(self.__call__)
     94     elif (not isinstance(self.build_fn, types.FunctionType) and
     95           not isinstance(self.build_fn, types.MethodType)):

AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute '__call__'
```

I do not wish to use *KerasClassifier* with a build function (example: `KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_dnn())` because I already have a trained network and it would take a lot of time to re-train.

Comment: what is `KerasClassifier`? It seems it is NOT class - and you CAN'T use `()` for this. Maybe you assigned something to this name - `KerasClassifier = ...`. Similar error you get when you try to use `()` with text: `"text"()` - `'str' object is not callable` - or with integer `1()` - `int' object is not callable`

Comment: KerasClassifier is a tensorflow wrapper *tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier*, meant to enable the use of Keras models in scikit_learn. In my case, I am using KerasClassifier to transform a DNN into a Classifier that I will then use in a scikit_learn ensemble, the sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.

Comment: your error suggests that you made `KerasClassifier = ...` so now it is NO `tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier` but normal variable. It may need to show full code to find problem.

Comment: Usually, you provide a build function to KerasClassifier. `KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_dnn())`. The constructor of KerasClassifier explicitly checks for the `__call__` function, because it will need it to call the function you provided, otherwise is just throws an error.

StackOverflow is against dropping entire codes, but I may provide a simple, runnable, reproducible example code if we must. Right now I'm finishing my exam project, so it will have to wait. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the best way to go about this is using SciKeras which is an enhanced fork of that wrapper class that enables a lot more functionality including functional model types and multi-output plus you can use pre-built models. I'm currently figuring out the same thing you are but this looks promising.

It looks like the first variable model for the scikeras.wrappers.KerasClassifier wrapper can be either a function that builds a keras model or an already built one.

from the scikeras documentation for the KerasClassifier constructor parameters:

model:Union[None, Callable[…, tf.keras.Model], tf.keras.Model],default None

```
Used to build the Keras Model. When called, **must return a compiled instance of a Keras Model** to be used by fit, predict, etc. If None, you must implement _keras_build_fn.
```

Additionally:

Attributes model_tf.keras.Model

```
The instantiated and compiled Keras Model. For pre-built models, this will just be a reference to the passed Model instance.
```

https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/generated/scikeras.wrappers.KerasClassifier.html

So for example your wrapper would look like so:

wrapped_model = KerasClassifier(model=pre_built_model_here,optimizer='Adam',...ect)